# Run i2c repeated start with pi4j

Tags: i2c

i´m using pi4j at my raspberry pi. It´s possible for me to write and read to and of devices which don´t need a repeated start.

But now i need to run the repeated start for a device.

I already tried this method:

```
int read (byte[] writeBuffer, int writeOffset, int writeSize,
                       byte[] readBuffer, int readOffset, int readSize) throws IOException
```

Between the write and read operations is a stop condition. I measured that with the oscilloscope.

I also tried to manipulate the combined parameter at

```
/sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined
```

following a solution i found at another forum. This also doesn´t work.

Maybe someone can show me the right direction for a solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The current driver is meant to handle repeated starts automatically.  The i2c_bcm2708 module was deprecated some years ago to be replaced by i2c_bcm2835.  You really ought to explain your software environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the driver but it doesn't work. Theres still the Stop condition in between. Any other ideas what i did wrong.